# Can I use IMAP to create a message in Exchange which can be opened, edited and send with a mail client?

Tags: php, exchange-server, imap

I spend the best part of today trying to create a message with PHP via IMAP in Exchange which I can open in my mail client, edit and send.

I can create a message in the Draft folder (or any other folder), I can set the FLAGGED flag using the UID, but I cannot set the message to Draft. I create the message with imap_append and set the flags with imap_setflag_full.

Either the setting of the \Draft flag is ignored or the \Draft flag is not the same as creating a message with the mail client and not sending it.
Is the first the case and am I overlooking something? Or is the later the case and am I expecting something IMAP / Exchange does not support?

Who has the experience to answer this?

As requested by cnd (base code without checks and validations):

```
// Create connection with the mail box
$this->o_mailbox = imap_open($o_company->draftbox, $o_company->username, $o_company->password);

// Create header
$a_header["from"] = $o_company->name.' <'.$o_company->address.'>';
$a_header["to"] = $s_to_name.' <'.$s_to_email.'>';
if(isset($s_cc)) $a_header["cc"] = $s_cc;
$a_header["subject"] = $s_subject;


// Add multipart to body
$a_body[0]["type"] = TYPEMULTIPART;
$a_body[0]["subtype"] = "mixed";

// Add content to body
$a_body[1]["type"] = TYPETEXT;
$a_body[1]["subtype"] = "html";
$a_body[1]["charset"] = "utf-8";
$a_body[1]["disposition.type"] = "inline";
$a_body[1]["description"] = "";
$a_body[1]["contents.data"] = str_replace('[BODY]', $s_message, $o_company->template);

// Loop trough the attachment
foreach ($a_attachments as $a_attachment) {

    $a_part["type"] = TYPEAPPLICATION;
    $a_part["encoding"] = ENCBINARY;
    $a_part["subtype"] = "pdf";
    $a_part["disposition.type"] = "attachment";
    $a_part["description"] = $a_attachment['name'];
    $a_part['disposition'] = array ('filename' => $a_attachment['name']);
    $a_part['type.parameters'] = array('name' => $a_attachment['name']);
    $a_part["contents.data"] = $a_attachment['data'];
    $a_body[] = $a_part;

}

// Create message in the draft box
$o_message = imap_mail_compose($a_header, $a_body);
$b_result = imap_append($this->o_mailbox, $o_company->draftbox, $o_message);
```

Comment: I can't help you with this particular combination, but most email clients are quite happy to treat any message in the Draft folder as a draft, and that's usually sufficient.

Comment: Sadly not eM-Client nor Outlook Web App

Comment: I installed Mozilla Thunderbird and it works on that mail client. No idea why it does not work on Outlook Web App and eM-Client. So if anyone knows, let me know.

Comment: If you have permission (api keys/password) to use IMAP, you can probably obtain an EWS token, which gives you access to the ews alternate endpoint - you simply format the data you've already got into an XML package, and send it to their endpoint, making sure to include <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly"> in there: that plonks it immediately into the drafts folder with the "draft" flag set, ready to send.  Lemme know if you want working code example.